# C# ASP.NET Reg Replace...Replace string with another string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this string here

```
string Thing1 = "12340-TTT";

string Thing2 = "&reg;"
```

I am looking to use reg replace to replace the `TTT` with `&reg`.

I am told using reg replace it does not matter if its uppercase or lowercase.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Is "TTT" always going to be "TTT"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    string one = "1234-TTT";

    string pattern = "TTT";
    Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
    string two = "&reg";
    string result = reg.Replace(one, two);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

should give you the desired Result. And just for a good read if you should ever need some more complicated Regular Expressions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xwewhkd1.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
string input = "12340-TTT";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "TTT", "&reg");

// Write the output.
Console.WriteLine(input);
Console.WriteLine(output);
Console.ReadLine();
```

This should do the trick.  You find "TTT" in a string and replace it with "&reg".

Answer (score 1):

correct me if i'm wrong but i think it is same with that of replacing a string on a variable like this:
    string Thing1 = "12340-TTT";

```
string Thing2 = Regex.Replace(Thing1 , "&reg;", "anyString");
```

got it from here:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace

cheers:)

Comment: @pinoy_ISF Have you tried to run the answer? A one-line-answer should at least be correct.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use the Regex.Replace method (documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx))

There are several overloaded versions, but the most direct one for this is the Regex.Replace(String input, String regexPattern, String replacementString) version:

```
string Thing1 = "12340-TTT";
string Thing2 = "&reg;";

string newString =  System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Thing1, "[Tt]{3}", Thing2);
```

If you are unfamiliar with regular expressions, the `[Tt]` define specific character group (any characters matching one of ones specified) and the `{3}` just indicates that it must be appear 3 times. So, this will do a case-insensitive search for a string of 3 T's (e.g., TTT, ttt, TtT, tTt, etc.)

For more on basic regex syntax, you can look here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Also, between the [RegexOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) you can pass to the regex there is the IgnoreCase to make it case insensitive:

```
string Thing1 = "12340-TTT";
string Thing2 = "&reg;"
var regex = new Regex("TTT", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
var newSentence = regex.Replace( Thing1 , Thing2  );
```